# Clone object or make a new with the same values

Tags: java, android, clone

I 've been read documents about clone object and my conclusion is clone objects is bad practice.

Is one of the best way to make a new object with the same values that another ?

Example:

```
    class Student {

    private String name;
    private int age;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public class AnotherClass{

Student guy = new Student();
guy.setName("Mike");
guy.setAge(20);

Student guy2 = makeClone(guy); //now i get a new guy with the same values of the first guy


private Student makeClone(Student oldStudent){

    Student newStudent = new Student();
    newStudent.setName(oldStudent.getName());
    newStudent.setAge(oldStudent.getAge());

    return newStudent;

  }

}
```

Comment: To clone an object you must make copy of everything, because the attributes will be references between them.  Now, about what is better or not I think that make an own clone method is better.

Comment: For reference: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71

Comment: Ty for the fast answer, i just what to know the best and most efficient way to clone.

Comment: Nowadays we got 1000 ways to do the same thing and someone mark this question possible duplicate from a question with 6 years ....

I just want to know if exist new ways to clone objects  or if some one have their own functions that make it easily.